# flutter sticky bottom navigation for all screens

Tags: android, flutter, widget, flutter-bottomnavigation

how do I created a bottom navigation bar fixed for all screens throughout the app and add a player on top of it fixed too. The desired goal is [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just register a widget i.e. `TabsScreen` once and use it everywhere on your screens. I also fixed the player on the top of the `BottomNavigationBar` so whether you're in your `HomeScreen()`, `SearchScreen()`, `LibraryScreen()` or `ProfileScreen()` doesn't matter, it will always remain there.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Music App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.brown,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const TabsScreen(),
        HomeScreen.routeName: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
        SearchScreen.routeName: (context) => const SearchScreen(),
        LibraryScreen.routeName: (context) => const LibraryScreen(),
        ProfileScreen.routeName: (context) => const ProfileScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/home';
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold();
  }
}

class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/search';
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold();
  }
}

class LibraryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/library';
  const LibraryScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold();
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/profile';
  const ProfileScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold();
  }
}

class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabsScreen> createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _pages = [
    {
      'page': const HomeScreen(),
      'title': 'Home',
    },
    {
      'page': const SearchScreen(),
      'title': 'Search',
    },
    {
      'page': const LibraryScreen(),
      'title': 'Library',
    },
    {
      'page': const ProfileScreen(),
      'title': 'Profile',
    },
  ];
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title']),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 90,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.brown,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        'Title',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Artist',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.pause,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 60,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: _selectPage,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 40),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 40),
              label: 'Search',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.my_library_books_sharp, size: 40),
              label: 'Library',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person, size: 40),
              label: 'Profile',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How to remove it from main player screen to cover entire screen??